# How to label duplicate geometry features avoiding text overlapping?

Tags: qgis, labeling

As shown in the screenshot, a point layer contains identical overlapping geometries. When labeling these points, the texts appear on the map in two rows. If there are more than two points, the texts appear overlapped and are unreadable. How could this case be solved? For example, each text value appears in a new text line.

[image]

Comment: A simple way would be to set the label placement to "Around Point" unless you want to get it all on the same column...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the label placement settings, increase the distance of the label so that all labels have enough place.

The larger the distance, the farther labels are away form the feature and the more labels are shown. You might use callout lines to connect the labels to the features.

[image]